# Exclude certain nodes when submitting jobs with qsub / torque?

Tags: torque, qsub

When submitting batch jobs with qsub, is there a way to exclude a certain node (by hostname)?

Something like

```
# this is just a pseudo command:
qsub myscript.sh --exclude computer01
```

Comment: What scheduler are you using? I don't know of native support in TORQUE for this, but Moab does support it.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how many nodes you would like available, there are a couple of options.

You could specify by name a specific  node that is acceptable:

```
qsub -l nodes=n006+n007
```

To exclude, say, one node out of a group, I would ask the administrator to assign a dummy property to all nodes but the one you want excluded.  Then you can request for that property.

Sources:

http://www.clusterresources.com/torquedocs21/2.1jobsubmission.shtml#nodeExamples
http://www.clusterresources.com/torquedocs21/2.1jobsubmission.shtml#resources