# Exclude (or include) specific nodes in PBS Pro

Tags: cluster-computing, pbs, qsub

I'm working on a cluster with 8 nodes; 4 nodes have python and 4 don't. How can I ensure that my python jobs only go to the nodes with python?

- I do not have admin rights on the cluster
- PBS Pro 13.1
- RedHat 5.11

This question has been asked before, but those solutions are not working for me:

- [excluding nodes from qsub command under sge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861220/excluding-nodes-from-qsub-command-under-sge)
- [Exclude certain nodes when submitting jobs with qsub / torque?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263327/exclude-certain-nodes-when-submitting-jobs-with-qsub-torque)
- [How to submit a job to a specific node in PBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392786/how-to-submit-a-job-to-a-specific-node-in-pbs)
- http://forum.pbsworks.com/index.php?/topic/107-how-to-exclude-a-specific-node-when-submitting-a-job/

I am able to select a single node using `qsub -l host=good_node1`. However, I am not able to select a group of nodes or exclude a single node or group of nodes. A subset of the many attempts that have not worked for me:

- `qsub -l host=!bad_node1`
- `qsub -l select=1:host=!bad_node1`
- `qsub -l host=!bad_node1&!bad_node2`
- `qsub -l nodes=good_node1+good_node2`

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: A post to the PBS Pro forum said that it was not possible. http://forum.pbsworks.com/index.php?/topic/674-exclude-or-include-specific-nodes-in-pbs-pro

Comment: The forum link is now broken.   Disappointed this is not possible!

Comment: I have only used SGE (not PBS), but I use this to exclude nodes: `-l h='!(bad_node1|bad_node2)'`. Perhaps you could check if that works on your system too.

Answer (score 1):

In our system, we have a specific property *vnode* with a unique host name. Let's say you want to exclude a node *zubat2*. You can exclude the node as follows:
`qsub -l select=1:vnode=^zubat2`

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I needed to know, and it should definitely be described on Metacentrum Wiki :)

Answer (score 0):

Know that it's a bit late. But the same issue happened and the following works for including a list of nodes (`good_node1` and `good_node2`).

```
qsub -l select=1:host=good_node1+1:host=good_node2
```

This worked for `pbs_version = 18.1.1`.